# TypeScript sub modules?

Tags: javascript, module, typescript, ecmascript-6, definitelytyped

Currently I do this:

```
import {validators} from 'marker';

validators.isEmail('foo@bar.com');
```

Instead, I would like:

```
isEmail('foo@bar.com');
// Without cheating by just: `const isEmail = validators.isEmail`
```

How do I `import` just the `isEmail` symbol?

---

Here's a little test-case, note that my actual module has many validators and other submodules (not just `validators`)

#### marker.d.ts

```typescript
declare var marker: marker.marker;

declare module marker {
    export interface marker {
        validators: IValidators;
    }

    export interface IValidators {
        isEmail(input: string): boolean;
    }
}

export = marker;
```

#### index.ts

```typescript
import * as vs from './validators'

export const validators = vs;
```

#### validators.ts

```typescript
export function isEmail(input: string): boolean { return true }
```

Comment: Hmm, actually `namespace`s might be the solution I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1):

You should cheat. But you can make that cheating prettier using further destructuring (more https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html). Instead of

```
const isEmail = validators.isEmail;
```

You can

```
const {isEmail} = validators;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note sure where exactly you don't want to include

```
 // Without cheating by just: `const isEmail = validators.isEmail`
```

Below solution is based upon assumption that you do not want isEmail to be defined in the ts file where you are using `validators.isEmail`.

Assuming `index.ts` your main file for marker package, you may expose all validator methods directly.

**index.ts**

```
   import * as vs from './validators'

   export const isEmail = vs.isEmail;
```

and use it like below,

```
  import { isEmail } from 'marker';

  isEmail('foo@bar.com');
```

you also have to make necessary changes in definition files.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that'd work, but is there no proper module layout; like in Python; that I can use? `import {isEmail} from 'marker.validators'`

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
const { validators: { isEmail } } = require('marker');

isEmail('aaa@bbb');
```